# Using TikZ fadings with a precompiled preamble causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, compilation-error, bugs, mylatexformat

I have noticed that I can use **TikZ fadings** in my documents and they work just fine. Also, I often use a **precompiled preamble** and that also work fine. However, when I try to use those two **together**, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is this a bug?
3. Is there something that I could do to make this work?

**Here are minimal steps to reproduce the problem.**

I use Ubuntu and TeX Live 2021, but the same thing happens on Windows and with TeX Live 2019.

First I create a class file called `test.cls` with the following contents:

```
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
```

And a file called `test.tex` with the following contents:

```
\documentclass{test}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=blue,path fading=south] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I compile `test.tex` with `pdflatex test.tex`, and get the following result:

[image: result 1]

Then I create `preamble.tex` with the following content:

```
\documentclass{test}
\csname endofdump\endcsname
\begin{document}
Preamble.
\end{document}
```

And compile it with `pdftex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx preamble.tex` to get `preamble.fmt`.

Then I change `test.tex` to

```
%&preamble
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=blue,path fading=south] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And when I compile it again, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Here is the full output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=preamble)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "test"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "preamble"
PRELOADED FILES:
    test.cls    
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
graphicx.sty    2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex

==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "test"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 2. (\begin{document})
==============================================================================
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file test.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I remove `path fading=south` from the TikZ picture so that `test.tex` contains the following:

```
%&preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[color=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the document works again and produces the following image:

[image: result 2]

Comment: well a segfault should be reported. But you get a message when creating the format `pdfTeX warning: pdftex.exe: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced` and this means that pdftex has opened the pdf to write some objects (for the fading) and they are now lost.

Comment: How and where should I report the segmentation fault?

Comment: I think I hit essentially the same error. MRE without TikZ fadings is [here](https://gist.github.com/tueda/569b43607499e335eeea99c1db166d74).

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same problem (fadings library + precompiled preamble)...

Comment: Not that I know of. I just stopped using fadings.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643238/precompiled-preamble-tikz-fadings-library#comment1603465_643238.