# Precompiled preamble + TikZ fadings library

Tags: preamble, tikz-fadings

It seems that the `fadings` library is not compatible with precompiled preambles.

MWE:

```
%&mwe
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}% Incompatible with precompiled preamble?

\endofdump

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[color=blue, path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When precompiling the preamble with:

```
pdftex -shell-escape -ini -jobname="mwe" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx mwe.tex
```

I get the following warning in terminal:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdftex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced.
```

and the document compilation fails. But when `\usetikzlibrary{fadings}` is commented and `path fading=south` is removed in the picture, there is no warning during preamble or document compilation... Any idea?

Comment: Seems like the library typeset/output something to the PDF. If I recalled correctly (can't find cite) you can't output anything to the PDF in precompiled preamble part.

Comment: Well, it's just incompatible, you can't do anything but to (rewrite/fix it yourself, contact author or) put it outside the preamble.

Comment: The `fadings` pgf library, which is loaded by the corresponding tikz library, declares (predefined) fadings, which will write XForm objects to PDF.

Comment: Hmmm... Hence the "dangling objects" that get discarded. Then I guess the only way is to load the `fadings` library outside the precompiled part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, the `fadings` library writes XForm objects to PDF, which explains the dangling objects that get discarded (no PDF is produced when precompiling the preamble).

A simple solution is thus to put `\usetikzlibrary{fadings}` after `\endofdump` (i.e. outside the precompiled part of the preamble).